# Aws SDK: CredentialsProviderError while integrating AWS v3 Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sts

I am trying to integrate Amazon STS v3 javascript sdk and am getting the below error.It seems to be requiring credentials in the new STS() initialization.What exact credentials is it expecting since I want to get the AWS credentials from Assume Role Command response.

**CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers**

```
import  { STS , AssumeRoleCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sts'

    function test() {
    
      const client = new STS({ region: 'us-east-1'});
      const params = {
        RoleArm: 'arn:aws:iam:21212134:role/app',
        RoleSessionName: 'Session1',
    
      }
      const command = new AssumeRoleCommand(params);
      const response = await client.send(command);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change RoleArm to RoleArn